# Pass by reference notation

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

My question is really straightforward and I believe understandable.
I've made this simple snippet to illustrate my conflict when I'm passing values by reference.

```
int main() {
 int a = 1;
 int &b = a;
}
```

I know that this is the correct way to do it but **how does it make sense to take the address of b and make it equal to the value of a**. Logically it should be: `int &b = &a;`

Comment: You cannot. Once a reference refers to something, it can never be changed to refer to something else.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I've taken on me to reopen this question. Your comment made me think you might have overlooked the question. Notice _"how does it make sense to take the address of b and make it equal to the value of a"_.

Comment: `&` does not always mean "take address of". In your code snippet it states the type of `b` is "reference to `int`".

Comment: You seem to be confusing [reference initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization) with the address-of operator. References are initialized using an _object_ of type `T` (`int` in your example) whereas the address-of operator yields a memory address (i.e. a pointer type).

Comment: Following that logic, you should also write `int *b = *a;`, but you don't; you write `int *b = &a;`.

Comment: I agree with you that the syntax for references in C++ makes no sense. It's just badly designed (in particular, it is not analogous to `*` / pointers).

Comment: @Richard What you're saying is that they just use the same notation (&) but in fact they are doing completely different things under the hood, right? Same as : 
int* p; p = &a;  where the value of a would be equal to *p. They both use * but in a different way.

Comment: @Ari It's better to think of them as completely different things that happen to have the same spelling. (That is, homonyms.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many operators are context-sensitive. The `&` "operator" could mean three different things depending on context:

1. It could be used when defining a reference

   ```
   int& r = a;  // The variable r is a reference of the variable a
   ```
2. It could be used to get a pointer to something

   ```
   int* p = &a;  // Here & is the address-of operator which returns a pointer
                 // Here it makes p point to the variable a
   ```
3. It could be the [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operator

   ```
   0x53 & 0x0f    // Here's a bitwise AND operation, the result is 0x03
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You're mistaken by the syntax. This is unhappy, but `&` is both the addressof operator *and* the token meaning "referente to".

```
int &b = a;
```

This declares the variable `b` to be of type `int&` (reference to an int) and initialized to `a`. No address whatsoever.

Comment: It was fair to reopen. I had not considered this source of confusion.